# Which frequency should be considered for inductor design in this FOT (fixed on time) PFC?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, power-factor-correction, ferrite

The PFC topology, I'm trying to design, works in transition mode, and switching frequency varies from 37 kHz to about 600 kHz according to the phase. The current flow through the inductor is as follows:

[image]

The frequency variation range is as follows:
[image]

Now, which frequency should be considered for inductor design?

The topology is also as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A borderline conduction mode (BCM) PFC exhibits wide frequency variations across the sinusoidal input. The minimum operating frequency is reached at the top of the sine wave. Usually, one design criterion for inductor selection is acoustic noise and you want to avoid switching frequency below 20 kHz at the sine top. Considering the highest inductor peak current occurring at low line, people usually determine the inductor by considering the minimum input line and the minimum acceptable frequency at that line level.

The below is excerpted from Chapter 6 of my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) and the graph shows the switching frequency evolution versus the input voltage:

[image]

I arbitrarily selected 20 kHz in this 150-W design example and you can see how the frequency touches that limit at the input voltage peak. You may consider a slightly higher value than 20 kHz to account for variations in load, input line and inductance.